# Cocoa/Objective-C - How do I step through an array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa, loops

Not sure if I am wording this correctly but what I need to do is iterate through an array sequentially but by 2 or 3 or 4 indices.

So you can iterate through an array like this

```
for(id arrayObject in NSArray) { 
    //do something amazing with arrayObject
}
```

which will iterate sequentially through each indexed object, [NSArray objectAtIndex: 0], [NSArray objectAtIndex: 1], etc.

so what if I just want object 0, 4, 8, 12, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not quite. The way you wrote it, you are omitting the class of the `arrayObject`, and you are iterating through the `NSArray` class name rather than an instance. Thus:

```
for (id arrayObject in myArray) {
    // do stuff with arrayObject
}
```

where `myArray` is of type `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`.

For instance, an array of `NSString`s

```
for (NSString *arrayObject in myArray) { /* ... */ }
```

If you want to skip parts of the array, you will have to use a counter.

```
for (int i=0; i< [myArray count]; i+=4) {
    id arrayObject = [myArray objectAtIndex:i]; 
    // do something with arrayObject
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo but kind of not relevant to my question. How can I step through an array by increments of 2 or 3 or 4 rather than just 1? - wait, part of your answer didn't show up at first, weird...ah, I see where my mistake was, I don't think I had it written as += but rather just +

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/enumerateObjectsUsingBlock%3a) and check the index inside the block:

```
[myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if( 0 == idx % 3 ){
        // Do work
    }
    else{
        // Continue enumeration
        return;
    }
}];
```

This would also allow you to operate on non-stride-based selections of your array, if necessary for some reason, e.g., `if( (0 == idx % 3) || (0 == idx % 5) )`, which would be much more difficult with a plain `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add, that there are also block-based enumeration methods, you could use.

```
NSMutableArray *evenArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (idx % 4 == 0) 
        [evenArray addObject:obj];
}];
```

Now `evenArray` will contain the objects with the indexes 0,4,8,… in the original array.

But often one will want to have just the filtered objects in the original array, and won't need a additionally mutable array.

I wrote some block-based convenient methods to achieve this:

```
array = [array arrayByPerformingBlock:^id(id element) {
    return element;
} ifElementPassesTest:^BOOL(id element) {
    return [array indexOfObject:element]%4 == 0;
}];
```

This will have the same result but hides the boilerplate code of creating and filling a mutable array.

You'll find my [arraytools on GitHub](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/arraytools).

Comment: You don't need to call `indexOfObject:obj` in the block -- the index is passed in as `idx`. Did you see my answer? The link to your arraytools is nice, though; thanks.

Comment: I have to admit, I didn't see ur answer. I started to write my answer few hours ago, when my laptop ran out of battery. At home I just finished it. You want me to delete that part?

Comment: No, no, that's totally unecessary; it was just a momentary flash of annoyance and confusion because I really didn't understand why you (who clearly know what you're doing) were using `indexOfObject:` Sorry for the apparent aggression.

Comment: Probably never a good idea to write an answer during several hours.

Comment: @JoshCaswell As I see in your profile you are also a Pythonista. My original idea for this arraytools was to have something similar to list comprehension.

Comment: List/dict comprehensions and _especially_ literals are the one big thing I miss in Obj-C from Python (and why I'm so disappointed about dropped PyObjC support in Xcode). I'm always trying to think of ways to make something like them. Will definitely take a close look at your tools.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an NSEnumerator:

```
NSEnumerator *arrayEnum = [myArray objectEnumerator]; //Or reverseObjectEnumerator
for (MyThingy *thingy in arrayEnum) {
    doThingyWithThingy(thingy);

    [arrayEnum nextObject]; //Skip element
}
```

You can have zero or more `nextObject` messages at either point. For every third object, you would have two `nextObject`s at the end of the loop:

```
for (MyThingy *thingy in arrayEnum) {
    doThingyWithThingy(thingy);

    //Skip two elements
    [arrayEnum nextObject];
    [arrayEnum nextObject];
}
```

Basically, this is the same way you gather multiple objects in a single pass through the loop, only without actually using the other objects.

You can also have zero or more `nextObject` messages before the loop to skip some number of objects before the first one you want.

(I hope you're doing this to an array you read in, not one you generated yourself. The latter case is a sign that you should consider moving from array manipulation to model objects.)